# split value of a parameter to multiple variables

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have à parameter that I passed to my xsl stylsheet from command line (I m using saxon 9), my parameter "emails" is as follows:

```
<xsl:param name="emails" select="emails"/>
```

and its value:
"john.doe@corp.com,jane.doe@corp.com,..."

My param can contain multiple emails.

I want to catch each email and assign it to a variable: $email1, $email2, $email3 ...

Once I have my variable I need to do some checks depending on these variables:

```
<xsl:if test="./text()=$email1">
     <!-- some operations -->
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="./text()=$email2">
     <!-- some operations -->
</xsl:if>
...
```

How can I proceed (XSLT 2 /xpath 2 ) ??

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xpath 2 you can use `tokenize` to split the mail addresses:

```
tokenize($emails, ",")
```

E.g, in XSLT probably:

```
 <xsl:variable name="email" select="tokenize($emails, ',')"/>
```

Then you can access them with `$email[1]`, `$email[2]`, ...

That makes more sense than using "$email1"

Comment: You can also pass a sequence in your `xsl:param` and skip `tokenize()` all together... `('john.doe@corp.com','jane.doe@corp.com')`

Comment: Benibela, don't understand how can I access each them to create my cases (if) since I don't know the number of emails ?
Daniel, sequence ?

Comment: tokenize returns a sequence. Then you can use `count($email)` to get the count (dracula?). And you probably should use use a loop instead many ifs

Comment: @Zatla00 - A sequence is an ordered collection of zero or more items (atomic values or nodes). If you give a more detailed example of what you are trying to do, someone can add some simple examples of using sequences to get the results you're looking for.